# Magento 2 : How to show ProductName and ProductPrice in custom email template?

Tags: magento2, email

This is my observer file from where I am passing values to `email_template.html`

```
 foreach($items as $item) {
        $productIds[]= $item->getProductId();
        $productName[]= $item->getSku(); 
        $productPrice[] = $item->getPrice();
  //      $productQuantity[]= $item->getQty();
    }

$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('order_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

How can I get the values of `$productName` and `$productPrice` in my email template.
I tried but not working

`email_template.html`

```
 <table class="email-items">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="item-info">{{trans "Items"}}</th>
                        <th class="item-info">{{trans "Qty"}}</th>
                        <th class="item-info">{{trans "Sku"}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{var $productName.getSku()}}</td>
                        <td>{{var myvar8|raw}}</td>
                        <td>{{var $productPrice.getPrice()}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In email template html, we can add layout and pass the order object to this layout. For instance, in your layout:

*email_template.html*

```
{{layout handle="sales_custom_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

Create your own layout:

*view/frontend/layout/sales_custom_email_order_items.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Order Items List" design_abstraction="custom">

    <body>
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Email\Items" name="items" template="email/items.phtml" cacheable="false">
             <!--Add more stuff here-->
        </block>

    </body>
</page>
```

And then, create `Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Email\Items` and `email/items.phtml`.

**We should take a look some default files:**

```
--vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html
--vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml
--vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml
--vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Email/Items/Order/DefaultOrder.php
--vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Email/Items.php
```

Comment: hello @khoa i tried this but phtml file is not calling ..

Comment: You should update your question with the block and phtml file.

Comment: Error filtering template: Renderer list for block "items" is not defined. I am getting this error in mail.

Comment: in core file of magento at endor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Email/Items.php there is not any single function ? what should i do ?

Comment: i think phtml file is calling now ...

Comment: i did exact copy from items.phtml in my phtml file ..

Comment: It's better if you understand the logic.

Comment: yes i got it thank you @khoa for your answer everything is working fine now.